# node.js command line programs(using commander node-module) opens index.js on execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, npm, jcommander

I am using **commander@2.9.0**. Attached the code below

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "commandtools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A command line example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
         "test": "node index.js hello"
  },
  "author": "aaa <aaa@xxx.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bin": {
    "cmdtools":"./index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
var program = require('commander');

program
    .version('0.0.1')
        .usage('<input>')
            .parse(process.argv);

            if(!program.args.length) {
                        program.help();
            } else {
                        console.log('Input: ' + program.args);
            }
```

On executing in command-line,

```
cmdtools Hello
```

index.js file opens without any output in the command-line

On executing,

```
npm test
```

The output is

```
Input: hello
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code outputs the arguments passed in the command line.

`npm test` outputs `Input: hello`, because `npm test` actually runs `node index.js hello`. If you change `node index.js hello` to `node index.js banana` the output will be `Input: banana`.

More about CLI arguments and how to access them here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

`cmdtools` command does not output anything, because there are no arguments passed to the `index.js` file.

When running `cmdtools` command you passed an argument to the `cmdtools` command and not to `index.js`. Nothing is outputted, because `program.help()` does not output anything to the console. You can test this by running `console.log('test')` instead of `program.help()`.

Comment: Understood about the scripts part. I am wondering why the `cmdtools Hello` doesn't output neither `Input: Hello` nor `help content`, instead opens the index.js file? I hope there must be an output. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I passed an argument `Hello`. Also in case if It don't pass any arguments it must output the help content right? Why does index.js file opens?Also what should be done to pass argument `Hello` with `cmdtools`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the npm module is

- Installed the package globally, but didn't execute [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)
- So, executed npm link and tried `cmdtools Hello` and got the expected output